# Sencha Touch list scroller does not refresh after loading new data with more items

Tags: javascript, list, extjs, touch, scroller

On Sencha Touch 2.3.1.410 (on Chrome 44.0.2403.157), the list scroller does not refresh after loading new data with more items. For example:
If I push a panel onto the display with a list that has 0 items in it, and then from that panel press a button that loads items into the list such that the list extends past the bottom of the window, the list scroller fails to recognize the longer list. The list correctly shows the top portion of the list, however, if you try to scroll down, the list simply snaps back to the top. You can see the scroller has not recognized the longer list.
It seems to me that there is an event that is not being fired, because if I push another panel on top of the panel with the list, and then pop back out, the scroller on the list is magically fixed, and I can scroll to the bottom.
Can anyone tell me how to send that event to the list scroller (or another better solution) so I don't have to push another panel to get it to work?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There will be only layout issue in your code. This is not problem of scroll events etc..